# Application for Screen-casting for Macintosh

Tags: screen-casting

I need to make a **Screen-cast**. This is, I need to capture my screen and audio from my computer and then after be able to edit this video.

Then I need an app for Macintosh.

Since I just need to do really basic editing tasks I've trying Camtasia and Screenflow, both of them works just fine, but both of these has important lacks imho.

**Screenflow**: doesn't have vectorial objects like "bubble speeches", "squares", etc.

**Camtasia**: you can not group or nest the tracks (keep in mind that this is Camtasia for Mac, which has less features that its Windows version)

Then, I'm just wondering what other app would I use.

Should I use Final Cut Pro to get all the features I need?

Answer (score 2):

I know you looked at ScreenFlow. Were you looking at the latest version--ScreenFlow 4? It does have some vectorial shapes (they're called Annotations):

- Line (arrow)
- Line
- Square (filled)
- Square
- Circle

Now, that doesn't get you speech bubbles and other abstract shapes. For those, you can use a text box with an image fill--unfortunately, you've got to supply your own image in that case.

ScreenFlow also accepts PDF and other image types as layers. This makes ScreenFlow able to import vector PDF's as "shapes" that one can use to add annotations such as the mentioned speech bubbles.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that grouping/nesting is coming in a future version of Camtasia.

If you are going for professional screencasting, there's Claquette.